# Intentando Usar la Api de vk en Php 2020

Tags: php, api, sdk

Buenas amigos tengo una duda al parecer el sdk de vk.com a cambiado y buscando en su información según ellos en este enlace esta la información para usar su sdk en php  :

https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk
Pero revisando su información no encuentro como enviar un post usando su librería .

Ase poco usaba esta otra librería https://github.com/fdcore/vk.api/blob/v2/src/vk.php

Y la manera de ocupar la era la siguiente para dejar un ejemplo :

```
<?php

    // Need to have the vk.php in the same directory.
    include 'vk.php';

    // Please complete the below with your details/credentials.
    $config['secret_key'] = '';
    $config['client_id'] = '';
    $config['user_id'] = '';
    $config['access_token'] = '';
    $config['scope'] = 'wall,photos,friends,groups';

    // Get a new instance of VK.
    $v = new Vk($config);

    // Define the attachment to insert, in this case an image.
    $attachments = $v->upload_photo(0, array('1737759.jpg'));

    // Post the message and image to your wall.
    $response = $v->wall->post(array(
       'message'=>'test 1737759.jpg',
       'attachments' => implode(',', $attachments)
    ));

?>
```

Hoy en día eso ya no funciona y en la pagina de sdk de vk no hay mucha información de su uso por eso pido alguna información o ejemplo para actualizar mi script

Comment: Lo instalas mediante composer? O descargas el código directamente de github?

Comment: usando composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar la [SDK](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk) de la API de VK es muy simple y disculpa la falta de explicación, pero tratare de ser lo mas entendible posible osea con un ejemplo de uso del código

Aquí el [ejemplo](https://php-download.com/package/vkcom/vk-php-sdk/example) de usó en el que me base.

### Editado

```php
<?php
$code = 'code';
$client_id = '';
$client_secret = '';
$redirect_url = '';
$v = '5.101';
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$vk = new VK\Client\VKApiClient($v, VK\Client\Enums\VKLanguage::SPANISH);
$oauth = new VK\OAuth\VKOAuth($v);
$response = $oauth->getAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_url, $code);
$access_token = $response['access_token'];
$vk->wall()->post($access_token, [
  'message' => 'Hello world'
]);
```

Comment: boy a probar y te confirmo ok

Comment: esta parte si no la explicaste como obtener esto $code = '';

Comment: El valor de `$code` es code. Edite mi repuesta

Comment: Acabo de probar el codigo y da este error:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught VK\Exceptions\VKClientException: VK\TransportClient\TransportRequestException: Failed curl request. Curl error 60: SSL certificate problem

Comment: Hay un problema se certificado de protocolo SSL, quizás tu sitio no es completamente HTTPS

Comment: si lo estoy probando desde localhost

Comment: Quizás eso no te funciona correctamente

Comment: ya lo resolví y era tal como lo dijiste ahora no encuentro como publicar una imagen